# Warning: 'blkb.si47x_rds_blockb::refined.si47x_rds_blockb::<anonymous struct>::groupType' is used uninitialized in this function

Tags: c++, arduino, typedef, esp32

**/Arduino/libraries/SI4735/SI4735.cpp: In member function 'char* SI4735::getRdsTime()':
/Users/rcaratti/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SI4735/SI4735.cpp:1534:5: warning: 'blkb.si47x_rds_blockb::refined.si47x_rds_blockb::::groupType' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     if (getRdsGroupType() == 4**

```cpp
/*
 * Block B data type
 * See also Si47XX PROGRAMMING GUIDE; AN332; pages 78 and 79
 * See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Data_System
 */
typedef union {
    struct
    {
        uint8_t address : 2;            // Depends on Group Type and Version codes. If 0A or 0B it is the Text Segment Address.
        uint8_t DI : 1;                 // Decoder Controll bit
        uint8_t MS : 1;                 // Music/Speech
        uint8_t TA : 1;                 // Traffic Announcement
        uint8_t programType : 5;        // PTY (Program Type) code
        uint8_t trafficProgramCode : 1; // (TP) => 0 = No Traffic Alerts; 1 = Station gives Traffic Alerts
        uint8_t versionCode : 1;        // (B0) => 0=A; 1=B
        uint8_t groupType : 4;          // Group Type code.
    } group0;
    struct
    {
        uint8_t address : 4;            // Depends on Group Type and Version codes. If 2A or 2B it is the Text Segment Address.
        uint8_t textABFlag : 1;         // Do something if it chanhes from binary "0" to binary "1" or vice-versa
        uint8_t programType : 5;        // PTY (Program Type) code
        uint8_t trafficProgramCode : 1; // (TP) => 0 = No Traffic Alerts; 1 = Station gives Traffic Alerts
        uint8_t versionCode : 1;        // (B0) => 0=A; 1=B
        uint8_t groupType : 4;          // Group Type code.
    } group2;
    struct
    {
        uint8_t content : 4;            // Depends on Group Type and Version codes.
        uint8_t textABFlag : 1;         // Do something if it chanhes from binary "0" to binary "1" or vice-versa
        uint8_t programType : 5;        // PTY (Program Type) code
        uint8_t trafficProgramCode : 1; // (TP) => 0 = No Traffic Alerts; 1 = Station gives Traffic Alerts
        uint8_t versionCode : 1;        // (B0) => 0=A; 1=B
        uint8_t groupType : 4;          // Group Type code.
    } refined;
    struct
    {
        uint8_t lowValue;
        uint8_t highValue; // Most Significant byte first
    } raw;
} si47x_rds_blockb;
```

```cpp
/*
 * Returns the Group Type (extracted from the Block B) 
 */
uint8_t SI4735::getRdsGroupType(void)
{
    si47x_rds_blockb blkb;

    blkb.raw.lowValue = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKBL;
    blkb.raw.highValue = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKBH;

    return blkb.refined.groupType;
}
```

```cpp
/* 
 * Gets the RDS time and date when the Group type is 4 
 */
char *SI4735::getRdsTime()
{
    // Under Test and construction
    // Need to check the Group Type before.
    si47x_rds_date_time dt;

    if (getRdsGroupType() == 4)
    {
        char offset_sign;
        int offset_h;
        int offset_m;

        // uint16_t y, m, d;

        dt.raw[4] = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKBL;
        dt.raw[5] = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKBH;
        dt.raw[2] = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKCL;
        dt.raw[3] = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKCH;
        dt.raw[0] = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKDL;
        dt.raw[1] = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKDH;

        /*
        y = (unsigned)(dt.refined.mjd - 15078.2) / 365.25;
        m = ((unsigned)(dt.refined.mjd - 14956.1) - (unsigned)(y * 365.25)) / 30.6001;
        d = (unsigned)(dt.refined.mjd - 14956) - (unsigned)(y * 365.25) - (m * 30.6001);

        if (m > 13) {
            m = 1;
            y++;
        }
        y = y % 100;
        */
        // sprintf(rds_time, "%02/%02/%04 %02d:%02d", d,m,y,dt.refined.hour, dt.refined.minute);

        offset_sign = (dt.refined.offset_sense == 1) ? '+' : '-';
        offset_h = (dt.refined.offset * 30) / 60;
        offset_m = (dt.refined.offset * 30) - (offset_h * 60);
        sprintf(rds_time, "%02d:%02d %c%02d:%02d", dt.refined.hour, dt.refined.minute, offset_sign, offset_h, offset_m);
        return rds_time;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: That works fine  on Arduino Atmega328 and Mega2560. But does not work on ESP32 and Arduino DUE.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard says:

> Bit-fields straddle allocation units on some machines and not on others.

So it's obvious if we look at

```
    struct
    {
        uint8_t content : 4;            // Depends on Group Type and Version codes.
        uint8_t textABFlag : 1;         // Do something if it chanhes from binary "0" to binary "1" or vice-versa
        uint8_t programType : 5;        // PTY (Program Type) code
        uint8_t trafficProgramCode : 1; // (TP) => 0 = No Traffic Alerts; 1 = Station gives Traffic Alerts
        uint8_t versionCode : 1;        // (B0) => 0=A; 1=B
        uint8_t groupType : 4;          // Group Type code.
    } refined;
```

that on machines where bit-fields don't *straddle allocation units*, `content` and `textABFlag` are packed into the first octet, `programType` (not fitting entirely in the first) together with `trafficProgramCode` and `versionCode` packed into the second, and `groupType` into a third octet. Given this,

```
uint8_t SI4735::getRdsGroupType(void)
{
    si47x_rds_blockb blkb;

    blkb.raw.lowValue = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKBL;
    blkb.raw.highValue = currentRdsStatus.resp.BLOCKBH;

    return blkb.refined.groupType;
}
```

of the local variable `blkb` this function sets only the first two octets (`lowValue` and `highValue`), but returns `groupType` from the uninitialized third octet.

In order to reliably put all those bit-fields into two octets, we have to use `uint16_t` rather than `uint8_t` - but bear in mind that:

> Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. 
I fixed an issue on the Arduino DUE, STM32 and ESP32 platforms and probably others that use the GCC compiler. The GCC compiler does not allow “Crosses boundary”. 
For example, a field formed by a set of bits cannot be formed by part of a byte and its subsequent one.

My solution was:
typedef union {
    struct
    {
        uint16_t content : 4;            // Depends on Group Type and Version codes.
        uint16_t textABFlag : 1;         // Do something if it chanhes from binary "0" to binary "1" or vice-versa
        uint16_t programType : 5;        // PTY (Program Type) code
        uint16_t trafficProgramCode : 1; // (TP) => 0 = No Traffic Alerts; 1 = Station gives Traffic Alerts
        uint16_t versionCode : 1;        // (B0) => 0=A; 1=B
        uint16_t groupType : 4;          // Group Type code.
    } refinedValues;
    struct
    {
        uint16_t lowValue;
        uint16_t highValue; // Most Significant byte first
    } raw;
    uint16_t value;
} si47x_rds_blockb;